# PowerShell remoting with two FQDNs

Tags: powershell, kerberos, winrm

We have servers with two FQDNs, e.g.

```
SERVER01.ADdomain.company.corp [10.0.0.1]
SERVER01.management.company.corp [192.168.0.1]
```

The first is the Active Directory FQDN and the second is an alternate NIC used for Backups & Management purposes.  Both are configured in DNS and forward- and reverse-DNS lookups work correctly.

We want to run PowerShell Remote commands such as:

```
Invoke-Command -scriptblock{hostname} -ComputerName SERVER01.ADdomain.company.corp
Invoke-Command -scriptblock{hostname} -ComputerName SERVER01.management.company.corp
```

The first command works but the second fails with the error:

```
WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: 
Cannot find the computer SERVER01.management.company.corp. Verify that the computer exists on the network
```

From what I can establish Kerberos authentication will only work over the Domain FQDN but my question is this: Is there any way to get the remote command working over the second FQDN?  If not, why not?  Any Microsoft documents to back this up would be appreciated.

Comment: So the second address is for something like an ILO or DRAC? What are you hoping to run against those addresses as they are not "computers" you can target? I'm going to say you likely cant do this because that is not Windows etc. If you are remoting to that is there documentation that tells you what you can do?

Comment: I would add the DNS tag to this question.

Comment: The second address is a NIC in the Windows Server - just an alternate route in/out.  e.g. our Backup agent on the server writes to BACKUP_SERVER.management.company.corp which keeps its traffic away from the primary NIC

Comment: This is a management interface to perform tasks in the event of failure and health updates. It is not a "direct" interface to the servers OS. I am going to guess that your ability to RDP is handled by that interface and it is passing it to the OS as a _backdoor_.

Comment: Check Windows Firewall as the Rule for 'Windows Remote Management' will need to be enabled for each Network Connection - both Domain and Private.